# Change compiz parameter by command line on XFCE

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

Compiz has a useful tool, `annotate`. This feature allows write freely on your desktop. But has a limitation, only one color is configured: it is not possible to switch between stroke colors.

**I would like to switch between annotate stroke colors quickly.**

The current `stroke color` is stored on configuration:

```
dh4@GLOW:~$ cat .config/compiz-1/compizconfig/Default.ini 
[core]
s0_active_plugins = core;composite;...;
s0_hsize = 4

[annotate]
s0_stroke_color = #0000FF
```

I tried to change value with `dconf`:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/Default/annotate/stroke-color "'#00AAAAAA'"
```

Also with `gsettings`:

```
gsettings set \
org.compiz.annotate:/org/compiz/profiles/Default/annotate/ stroke-color '#00AAAAAA'
```

No errors appears on execute commands, but has no effect, neither restarting `compiz`.

**How can I do to change and apply parameter from script or command line to compiz without ccsm gui on XFCE?**

Answer (score 1):

You can do it activating dbus. Then just execute:

```
dbus-send \
  --print-reply \
  --type=method_call \
  --dest=org.freedesktop.compiz \
         /org/freedesktop/compiz/annotate/screen0/stroke_color \
         org.freedesktop.compiz.set \
         string:"#00ffffff"  #<-- new color
```

- Red color is `#ff0000ff`
- Blue color is `#0000ffff`